# Detect "was previous page from the same magento website?" If yes: then dont show APP notice

Tags: magento2, session, popup

We have an APP popup that popups in mobiles. It depends on a meta param in the header.

We would like to create an if / else scheme like

- if new visitor: print the meta param
- else (if not new and already on site: : do not bother the visitor

Is there a quick session() method for this that we could use?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use JS? Something like this:

```
var referrer = document.referrer;
var yourDomain = "example.com";

if(referrer.indexOf(yourDomain) !== -1){
        console.log("Came from your domain!")
}else{
        console.log("Did not come from your domain.")
}
```

Comment: No js i think for metas